# java postgresql- No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a stored procedure as follows in postgresql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_orderline(order_id integer, prod_id integer, prodname text, rate numeric, ordered_qty numeric, dispatched_qty numeric, balance_qty numeric, photonum text, remarks text, create_station_id integer, create_stationtype text, create_time text, create_user_id integer, tran_time text, tran_user_id integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
   INSERT INTO bakingfactory.orderline
     (orderline_id, order_id, prod_id, prodname, rate, ordered_qty, 
       dispatched_qty, balance_qty, photonum, remarks, create_station_id, 
       create_stationtype, create_time, create_user_id, tran_time, tran_user_id)
   values 
     (default,order_id, prod_id, prodname, rate, ordered_qty, 
       dispatched_qty, balance_qty, photonum, remarks, create_station_id, 
       create_stationtype, create_time, create_user_id, tran_time, tran_user_id) 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION insert_orderline(integer, integer, text, numeric, numeric, numeric, numeric, text, text, integer, text, text, integer, text, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I am trying to insert it using java as follows:

```
CallableStatement cstorderline = conn.prepareCall("{call insert_orderline(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                            cstorderline.setInt(1, lastinsertid);
                            cstorderline.setInt(2, prodid);
                            cstorderline.setString(3, proname);
                            cstorderline.setDouble(4, rate);
                            cstorderline.setDouble(5, ordered_qty);
                            cstorderline.setDouble(6, dispatched_qty);
                            cstorderline.setDouble(7, balanced_qty);
                            cstorderline.setString(8, photonum);
                            cstorderline.setString(9, notes);
                            cstorderline.setInt(10, create_station_id);
                            cstorderline.setString(11, create_station_type);
                            cstorderline.setString(12, timewithmilsec);
                            cstorderline.setInt(13, create_user_id);
                            cstorderline.setString(14, timewithmilsec);
                            cstorderline.setInt(15, trans_user_id); 
                            cstorderline.executeUpdate();
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function bakingfactory.insert_orderline(integer, integer, character varying, double precision, double precision, double precision, double precision, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 15
```

I have type `numeric` in my database with precision values. For type numeric I am simply using `double`. Is that the right way?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name buddy take a look on this!!

Comment: Well, what data are you trying to insert?

Comment: @WeareBorg I am inserting double. is it right?? `SetDouble`

Comment: For which value are you getting an error, and you can insert double for numeric. But why are you inserting values this way? Looks very buggy.

Comment: Can you suggest a correct way?

Comment: @We are Borg please check the error code and if you have any suggestions please tell!!

Comment: does `insert_orderline` actually belong to `bakingfactory` schema?

Comment: also, any chance that some of the values passed are `null`?

Comment: yah @Vladimir it lies in that schema

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm getting the same error with same `position: 15`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple explanations for your error.

**First explanation**

You have created a function `insert_orderline` but the Java code expects that this function in included in the `bakingfactory` schema (Probably you have setup `bakingfactory` as the default schema of the connected user of the Java app).

So, create the function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bakingfactory.insert_orderline
```

instead of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_orderline
```

**Second explanation**

You should use `double precision` in your function definition instead of `numeric` data types.

Comment: I bet $5 the reason is the first one! :)

Comment: @Alexandros changed as per your suggestions the error still persists. The error code specifies `Position: 15` is that a clue?